# Integrate two XML schemas

Tags: xml, schema, integrate

i have a very complex XML schema where, inside the element "CustomData", is possible to insert precisely custom datas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <xs:element name="CustomData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="UniqueIdentifier" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

Inside "CustomData" there are two mandatory element: "Name" and "UniqueIdentifier"

I have create my own custom datas with this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:attribute name="du">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="S_L"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="RI_L"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="PC_L"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="G_L"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="UC_L"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:complexType name="du_type">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                <xs:attribute ref="du" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="CustomData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Rated_Voltage" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Max_Voltage" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Min_Voltage" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Rated_Frequency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Max_Frequency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Min_Frequency" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Rated_Current" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Max_Current" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Min_Current" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Rated_Power_Factor" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Num_Sources" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Source_Type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="H"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="I"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="F"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="T"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Q"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="LS"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="DL"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Replaceable_Sources" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Nominal_Source_Power" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_InsulationClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_IP_Body" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_IP_Box" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_IK" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Surge" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_IDPhotobiological_Risk" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Threshold_Distace_PhRisk" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Rated_Life" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Failure_Index" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Luminous_Efficacy" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Dff" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Uclass" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="U1"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="U2"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="U3"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="U4"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="U5"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CAM_G_Class" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value=""/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="G*1"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="G*2"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="G*3"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="G*4"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="G*5"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="G*6"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CAM_IPEA" type="du_type" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_Warranty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_ID_Mark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="CAM_ID_Mark_Link" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How i can integrate my schema inside the "CustomData" element of the main one?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783250/xml-integration-from-different-xml-schemas

Comment: Is it possible to change the first schema, for example to replace CustomData with an abstract element, so that you can put your own CustomData in the substitution group of the abstract element?

Comment: No, is not possibile to change the first schema